# Using Terraform to create N number of resources in an automated way

Tags: terraform, github-actions, terraform-provider-azure

#### Summary

I am trying to implement a self-service pipeline using GitHub Actions that will provision a stack of Azure infrastructure, specifically Azure container instances, using Terraform. For N number of feature branches, it should trigger a deployment of those new resources to Azure. For instance "feature-X" will have deployed a container group "feature-X". If another developer creates "feature-Z", then it should trigger a deployment of "feature-Z" container group, and so on. These all need to co-exist at the same time until they are destroyed.

I haven't been able to find any documentation on this use-case, which I find strange since Terraform is frequently used to provision new infrastructure in automated CI/CD pipelines.

When running Terraform plan in a GitHub Actions workflow, instead of creating new resources, Terraform is still looking at the state of the existing container group. When the "name" property changed, it wanted to modify the existing resource, so it destroyed the existing one and creates the new one in its place. I am not using Terraform Cloud. The only workaround I can think of is to inject a variable into the backend.tf to create a brand new Azure remote backend container to store and initialize a new Terraform state. Unfortunately Terraform doesn't support built-in variables in the backend configuration file, so it will have to be forced in via a bash script. I'm not sure if there's a better approach to this.

My GitHub actions workflow:

```
permissions:
  id-token: write # required to use OIDC authentication
  contents: read # required to checkout the code from the repo

name: feature-deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "feature/**"

jobs:
   build:
     name: build-feature
.... workflow that builds the docker image and uploads to Azure Container Registry.

  deploy-aci:
    name: deploy-aci
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      BRANCH_NAME: ${{ github.ref_name }}
      ARM_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_CLIENT_ID }}
      ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
      ARM_TENANT_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_TENANT_ID }}
      ARM_USE_OIDC: true
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: aci/terraform/azure-container-instances
    needs: build
    
    steps:
    - name: Checkout aci terraform repo
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        repository: MyOrg/azure-feature-environments
        path: aci
        token: ${{ secrets.ACI_REPOSITORY_ACCESS_TOKEN }}

    - name: Setup terraform ENV variables
      run: echo "TF_VAR_branch_name=${{ env.BRANCH_NAME }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

    - name: Setup terraform
      uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2

    - name: Terraform Init
      id: init
      run: terraform init

    - name: Terraform Validate
      id: validate
      run: terraform validate -no-color

    - name: Terraform Plan
      id: plan
      run: terraform plan -no-color -input=false

    - name: Terraform Apply
      run: terraform apply -auto-approve -input=false
```

#### What I tried:

Assume that Terraform already provisioned resources with name "branch1". Then I trigger the GitHub action workflow on a push event, which passes in the Github branch name as an environment variable to the Terraform action (setup-terraform action). Assume the branch name is "branch2".

#### What I expected to happen:

Terraform will create a new Azure container group (and other supporting resources) with the name "branch2" and it will NOT destroy resources named "branch1".

#### What actually resulted:

Terraform destroyed Azure resource with name "branch1" and created a new resource in its place (replaced it) with name "branch2".

Comment: Can you add the code you have?

Comment: @MarkoE I've added the code for the GitHub Actions workflow. I don't think adding more code examples will help illustrate my question, since this is more of a design issue than a coding issue. The terraform code is the same as any other terraform code, the difference being that I want it to "stamp out" multiple instances, one for each feature branch, without destroying the existing resources that is managed in the TF state.

Comment: I agree with @MarkoE, it wouldn't hurt to provide the tf code as well

Comment: one idea is to script out the branch names and read those in tf and for_each through them for provisioning.  That way your tf definition will always be in sync with your container group per branch.

Comment: @spinalfrontier The issue with that approach is I don't know the branch names ahead of time. They are created as a developer creates them. The best solution I've come up with so far is to just generate the backend.tf file using the branch name, that way it starts with a blank TF state every time the branch changes. I tested this, and it's not wiping my existing resources anymore.

Comment: @alig227 you can add a simple script to query git for the branch names at the start of your run